# Explicitly set multiple transports in SignalR .Net client

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Is it possible to explicity set two (or more) transports in the SignalR .Net Client?

I can set a single transport using code such as:

```
_hubCn.Start(new LongPollingTransport());
```

In the Javascript client it can be done using:

```
connection.start({ transport: ['webSockets','longPolling'] });
```

However I haven't found an overload on the .Net client that allows for this. Is there some other way?

For a little bit of context, this particular usage is within a Silverlight 5 application. I'm still exploring what differences this makes over normal .Net or JS uses.

Comment: What's the point? In javascript you don't know what browsers people will be using. This is not the case in .net, it already supports every transport method! If you specified multiple transports, it would just use the first one as it is always available.

Comment: .Net might support the transports, but the host server might not, and the intervening proxies might also not depending on configuration. I would like to be able to tune it.

Comment: I never knew the javascript implementation handled those cases...

Comment: If JS isn't able to establish comms on one transport, it'll drop to the next. But if you know for a fact that one transport is a no-go, you can omit it completely and save everything some work. In the end it'll usually arrive at Long-polling, which should be fine through most setups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AutoTransport:

```
var httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
_hubCn.Start(new AutoTransport(httpClient, 
    new IClientTransport[] 
    { 
        new WebSocketTransport(httpClient), 
        new LongPollingTransport(httpClient)
    }));
```

As documented in the [source code](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/Transports/AutoTransport.cs) the list you provide is a:

> List of transports in fallback order

Answer (score 1):

If you don't provide a transport when you start a connection with the .Net client it will use so called `AutoTransport` which basically will try different transports until it finds one that works. Note that depending on the platform (e.g. .NET Framework vs. Silverlight/Portable) the list of transports available to the AutoTransport may be different (currently you will get WebSockets, ServerSentEvents and LongPolling on .NET and ServerSentEvents and LongPolling on Portable). However if you want to exclude (or add - e.g. there is a Windows Phone 8.1 (universal app) specific implementation of WebSocket transport) a transport you can manually create an `AutoTransport` and provide transports you want to use.